# Unrecognized selector sent to instance?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios5, mapkit

I have seen that a few others have had this problem as well.
I'm trying to follow a tutorial online that shows how to create animated pins on a MapView.

I have implemented the code as shown in the tutorial and the project builds fine except I receive this exception:

```
-[MKPointAnnotation iconN]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

I have a subclass of 'MKPinAnnotationView' and in the .m file I create this method:

```
- (void)setAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation {
    [super setAnnotation:annotation];

    //Place *place = [[Place alloc] init];
    Place *place = (Place *)annotation;


    //The following line is where the program sends "SIGABRT"
    icon = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"pin_%d.png", [place.iconN intValue]]];
    [iconView setImage:icon];
}
```

Here are a few parts from my "model" which is called Place.h/.m.
Here is where I create the property for 'iconN'.

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSNumber *iconN;
```

And here I synthesize it:

```
@synthesize iconN = _iconN;
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT:
Here is the Place.h and Place.m

```
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>


@interface Place : NSObject <MKAnnotation> {
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
    NSString *title;
}

@property (retain, nonatomic) NSNumber *iconN;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;

- (id)initWithLong:(CGFloat)lon Lat:(CGFloat)lat iconNumber:(NSNumber *)iconNumber;

@end
```

And the Place.m

```
#import "Place.h"

@implementation Place
@synthesize coordinate;
@synthesize iconN = _iconN;
@synthesize title;

- (id)initWithLong:(CGFloat)lon Lat:(CGFloat)lat iconNumber:(NSNumber *)iconNumber {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat, lon);
        self.iconN = iconNumber;
    }

    return self;
}

- (NSString *)title {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Bus: %d", [self.iconN intValue]];
}

- (NSString *)subtitle {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"bus[%d] from database.", [self.iconN intValue] - 1];
}


@end
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with the MapKit, but the thing that sticks out for me in this: `-[MKPointAnnotation iconN]: unrecognized selector sent to instance` is that the class is `MKPointAnnotation`. So the annotation you're receiving isn't actually a `Place` object, it's an `MKPointAnnotation` object - you can't just cast to `Place`. I suspect the root of your problem is where you create your annotation object in the first place.

Comment: Does Place implement the MKAnnotation protocol?  Is "annotation" a kind of Place?  In other words, would `[annotation isKindOfClass:[Place class]]` return true?

Comment: @pmjordan
You nailed it!

I went back and looked through my project. I was adding 3 other annotations using the method 'addAnnotations:' and for some reason the 'setAnnotation' method was being called when I was adding them even though they were not "Place" objects. Maybe I should check if the object being passed is a 'Place' object first, and if it is not, do nothing?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot convert a `MKAnnotation` to a `Place` just by casting it. This line is wrong.

```
Place *place = (Place *)annotation;
```

You should post your `Place.h` and `Place.m` files if you're still stuck. You need to either set the iconN property on a new Place object, or create an init method in the Place class that accepts the `MKAnnotation` object as a parameter and sets it own internal values accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You are sending the message to the annotation but you seem to have subclasses the annotation view.

Answer (score 1):

In the line

```
Place *place = (Place *)annotation;
```

has the variable place of annotation variable class (MKPointAnnotation), you are not able to bring the master class variable to a subclass in this way. Instead you'll have to make a constructor for Place from MKPointAnnotation and perform a check in the setAnnotation method that annotation is of MKPointAnnotation.

Answer (score 0):

*Posting as an answer what was originally just a comment:*

I'm not familiar with the MapKit, but the thing that sticks out for me in this: -[MKPointAnnotation iconN]: unrecognized selector sent to instance is that the class is MKPointAnnotation. So the annotation you're receiving isn't actually a Place object, it's an MKPointAnnotation object - you can't just cast to Place. I suspect the root of your problem is where you create your annotation object in the first place.